# Manipulating matrix elements in tensorflow

Tags: matrix, indexing, element, variable-assignment, tensorflow

How can I do the following in tensorflow?

```
mat = [4,2,6,2,3] #
mat[2] = 0 # simple zero the 3rd element
```

I can't use the [] brackets because it only works on constants and not on
variables. I cant use the slice function either because that returns a tensor and you can't assign to a tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
var1 = tf.Variable(initial_value=[2, 5, -4, 0])
assignZerosOP = (var1[2] = 0) # < ------ This is what I want to do

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

print sess.run(var1)
sess.run(assignZerosOP)
print sess.run(var1)
```

## Will print

```
[2, 5, -4, 0] 
[2, 5, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't change a tensor - but, as you noted, you can change a variable.

There are three patterns you could use to accomplish what you want:

(a)  Use [`tf.scatter_update`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update) to directly poke to the part of the variable you want to change.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(initial_value=[2, 5, -4, 0])
b = tf.scatter_update(a, [1], [9])
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as s:
  s.run(init)
  print s.run(a)
  print s.run(b)
  print s.run(a)
```

> [ 2  5 -4  0]
>
> [ 2  9 -4  0]
>
> [ 2  9 -4  0]

(b)  Create two `tf.slice()`s of the tensor, excluding the item you want to change, and then `tf.concat(0, [a, 0, b])` them back together.

(c)  Create `b = tf.zeros_like(a)`, and then use `tf.select()` to choose which items from `a` you want, and which zeros from `b` that you want.

I've included (b) and (c) because they work with normal tensors, not just variables.

Comment: Thanks alot, it was definately of help and I could work with that but it would be somewhat combersome.What If I actually needed to change the tensor? Is there no way to do that?
I want to implement network visualisation and I need to propagate an image up to an activation layer, zero all activations except a random one a then propagate that back.

Comment: Tensors are immutable.  In general, if you want to save and change state, you would store it in a variable, which you *can* mutate.  But otherwise, you just create a new tensor derived from the original and use that.  In the case you're describing, that's probably the approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I solved the problem by using a new tensor derived from the original as you suggested.

Comment: I can't find `tf.select` in my tensorflow version 1.0.0. Is there a replacement?

Comment: `tf.select` is changed to `tf.where` just like `np.where` since tf 1.0.

Comment: What would you in the following situation?Suppose I have a tensor in Tensorflow that its values are like:

A = [[0.7, 0,2, 0.1],[0.1, 0.4, 0.5]]
I also asked this question here. 
How can I change this tensor into the following:

B = [[1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1]]

In other words I want to just keep the maximum and replace it with 1.
Any help would be appreciated. I also asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834739/argmax-on-a-tensor-and-ceiling-in-tensorflow