# Tensorflow: How to zero a random element?

Tags: tensorflow

In Tensorflow, I would like to create a mask of all ones, except a single element, where the element location is chosen randomly. Specifically, I would like to create a random mask of either [0,1,1,1] or [1,1,0,1]

I tried:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# randomly draw the column to select (either column 0 or 2)
COLselect = tf.to_int64(tf.greater(tf.random_uniform((1,)), 0.5))
column_num = COLselect*2

ones_mask = tf.Variable(numpy.ones((4,)))
```

And I am stuck on how to create a new mask that nulls column_num column of ones_mask.

I tried following [Manipulating matrix elements in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769944/manipulating-matrix-elements-in-tensorflow), but failed because the column is a tensor.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use `tf.one_hot` with a custom `on_value` and `off_value`, and use a random integer as the index. You can use `tf.reshape` to get the output in the right shape.

Answer (score 0):

With Tensorflow r0.10 :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# randomly draw the column to select (either column 0 or 2)
COLselect = tf.to_int64(tf.greater(tf.random_uniform((1,)), 0.5))
column_num = COLselect*2

ones_mask = tf.Variable(np.ones((4,)))
mask_op = tf.scatter_update(ones_mask,column_num,[0])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
sess.run(mask_op)
```

give me :

> array([ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.])

or

> array([ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.])

The only problem is that tf.scatter_update modify the variable. It's normal, but when you want call mask_op a second time, you should get :

> array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.])

So initialize `ones_mask` before  each `mask_op` call.